# Variables in Objective-C/Cocoa-touch

Tags: ios, variables

I have this equation here:

```
gas.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%f", totalDistance  *0.000621371/30  *4.00];
```

I want the 30 and 4.00 a variable, so the user can change the number any time in setting. Thank You!!

Comment: I changed your title and tags. XCode has nothing to do with the question you are asking.

Comment: Just define it in constants somewhere so that whenever you want to make a change it becomes easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create them as variable as Int and double in place of that like

```
Int varforInt;
double varfordouble;
gas.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%f", totalDistance  *0.000621371/varforInt  *varfordouble];
```

You can get the value in these variable ,it will change dynamically.

**Updated :-** get the text and there is one method intValue so use that one `[text intValue]`

Comment: How can I get the variables by a textfield?

Comment: what do you by getting variable? it would be a value i guess?

Comment: int varforInt = [MPGSaveDate.text intValue];
    int varfordouble = [MoneySaveDate.text intValue];
    gas.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f" , totalDistance  *0.000621371/varforInt  *varfordouble];    I updated the code and the textfield is saying nan :(     I will show more code if needed :(

Comment: I also I want to mention my textfield is getting up-to-date by using NSUserDefault :)

Comment: if([[MoneySaveDate text] length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Yes");
    }  I ran this and its saying yes in the debugger :)